# Provide url value externally to angularjs file from external config file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, configuration, web-config

I am new to Web development and so to angularjs.I am trying to implement it in my app. This app consumes REST services to fetch and display data.

Following is my code, which is working fine.

JS:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('oneAppCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.documentValue = {};

    $http({method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:70/DocumentRESTService.svc/GetDocuments/'              
           })
        .success(function(data){ alert('Success!');$scope.documentValue=data;})
        .error(function(data){ alert('Error!');$scope.documentValue=data;})
        .catch(function(data){ alert('Catch!');$scope.documentValue=data;});

    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    });
```

Here as you see I have made two service calls.

My question is , in real life application i wouldn't want these url's to be hardcoded in my app. Instead i would want to keep these url's in some file (call it config file) and read it from there in real time.

I tried to search for this on google and SO but not really sure what exact terminology should i use to search the same.

Any guidance/references would be much appreciated.

Comment: start by moving the actual requests to a service. Then the service is available to all controllers, directives and even other services and routing resolves. Service can start out having a `baseUrl` but that can also be move further up to runtime config block too or a constant or a value and injected into numerous services. Lots of flexibility so how you configure app is a bit too broad and would be a lot dependent on app itself

Answer (score 0):

It depends what server you are using. Also how are you reading config file. is it accessible on server while request ?

If you are using JAVA based application,
when page request comes, you can get URL from config file, and add it to your HTML.

or

If URL doesn't change, you can add it HTML,

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="https://url" />
```

and in your js file somewhere during config or in run method or in before calling http call,
can get URL

```
var httpURL = document.getElementById("url").value;
```

hope, this will help you.

Comment: how could this be achieved if it is not a Java app? Thanks